# Android: how to display list of videos in recyclerview from external storage or galley

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-videoview, android-gallery

I want to display each and every video from my mobile phone to recycler view android. i succeed to display list of images from specific location of directory bt not with videos

Comment: What do you use to show the video? Exoplayer or another library?

Comment: can you show some code ?